# performance degrades during concurrent sqlite3 writes

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, error-handling, sqlite

Writing a test suite for a cloud based API. I need to seed a database with fake user data - with part of the data coming from an API server - (the API key and secret are received from the API server after registering with the fake generated user details)

When trying to write records to a file using sqlite3 with node, I tried writing the logic in a naive manner, without any error checks - but it was failing with numerous SQLITE_BUSY database locked errors.

Then I added code to retry in case of an error, but was insufficient - ended up with corrupt tables, and so I added transactions as suggested in #node.js on freenode.

Now, it works. However the problem is that it is pathetically slow - takes up to 5 minutes for around 50 records. Also, I need to pass in a retries parameter of roughly `number_of_users * 2` in order for the process to complete successfully or else it bails out. Something is not correct, but I cannot pin it down. SQLite3 performance cannot be this slow.

What is wrong?

```
TestController.prototype.connectToDb = function () {
    var db = new sqlite3.Database(this.dbpath);
    return db;
}

TestController.prototype.writeUserToLocalDatabase = function (retries,username,useremail,password,api_key,api_secret, callback_after_all_users_have_been_added) {
    var dbase = this.connectToDb();
    var controller = this;

    if (retries < 0) {
       console.log("Bailing out of writeUserToLocalDatabase after max retry attempts");
       return;
    }

    dbase.run("BEGIN TRANSACTION");
    //console.log("Try #"+retries);
    var stmt = dbase.prepare("insert into user_table values(?,?,?,?,?)", function(err) {
        if(err !== null) {
          console.log("Error when trying to write user to database in prepare! "+err);
          dbase.run("ROLLBACK");
          dbase.close(function(err){if(err !== null) {console.log("Close failed in in prepare "+err);}});
          controller.writeUserToLocalDatabase(--retries,username,useremail,password,api_key,api_secret, callback_after_all_users_have_been_added);
       }
    });

    stmt.run(username,useremail,password,api_key,api_secret, function(err) {
       if(err !== null) {
          //console.log("Error when trying to write user to database in run! "+err);
          stmt.finalize();
          dbase.run("ROLLBACK");
          dbase.close(function(err){if(err !== null) {console.log("Close failed in in run "+err);}});
          controller.writeUserToLocalDatabase(--retries,username,useremail,password,api_key,api_secret, callback_after_all_users_have_been_added);
       }
       else {
          stmt.finalize(function(err) {
             if(err !== null && err !== undefined) {
                console.log("Error when trying to write user to database in finalize ! "+err);
                dbase.run("ROLLBACK");
                dbase.close(function(err){if(err !== null) {console.log("Close failed in in finalize "+err);}});
                controller.writeUserToLocalDatabase(--retries,username,useremail,password,api_key,api_secret, callback_after_all_users_have_been_added);
             }
             else {
                dbase.run("COMMIT");
                controller.appendToUserFile(useremail,password,api_key,api_secret);
                controller.pending_db_writes_for_user--;
                if (controller.pending_db_writes_for_user <= 0) {
                   console.log("Finished writing all users, now invoking db.close with callback");
                   dbase.close(callback_after_all_users_have_been_added);
                }
                else {
                   console.log("Remaining users to add: "+controller.pending_db_writes_for_user);
                   dbase.close(function(err){if(err !== null) {console.log("Close failed in after adding user "+err);}});
                }
             }
          });
       }
    });
}
```

Update: The only way I can get sane performance is by throttling the sqlite3 writes using async.queue with a queue size of 1.

Comment: one word: [sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com/)

Comment: I see... thanks, will look into it. But the default behavior of the sqlite3 module is puzzling.

Comment: update: The only way I can get some semblance of sane performance is by using async.queue with a queue size of 1 to throttle the db writes.

Comment: given that sqlite is a single file, that is not surprising. To my knowledge the sqlite3 node module just offers sqlite3, not any additional complex db management, so it's still going to be a single file, into which you need to write data in series, not in parallel. It's also why sqlite is great for prototyping and as read-often/write-occasionally store. If you need concurrent writes, you use a 'real' database instead.